# ScalaPB type class instance on the generated message companion object

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers, scalapb

Suppose there is a proto `MyMessage` and a type class `TypeClass[T]`.

Is it possible to have a custom instance `TypeClass[MyMessage]` in the generated companion object of `MyMessage`, so any `(implicit TypeClass[Message])` would get automatically resolved without any import?

The solution I've thought of is to have a trait defining the implicit instance

```
trait MyMessageCompanionTrait {
  implicit val myMessageType = new TypeClass[MyMessage] = ???
}
```

and then make that extend the companion object

```
message MyMessage {
  option (scalapb.message).companion_extends = "MyMessageCompanionTrait";

  int32 field = 1;
}
```

Obviously this adds a circular dependency in the build.

Comment: Probably you'd have to write your own plugin - https://scalapb.github.io/docs/writing-plugins

Comment: I think the solution you outlined should work. Can you try it? If not, I'm open to consider solving this use case as a feature request. Feel free to file an issue on the project's github.